# Attach an Animated Texture to a Character in Unity

Tags: unity, textures

Is it possible to have an animated texture of facial features on a characters face in unity? (I haven't made the game yet, I'm researching).  I would like to achieve a cartoon effect.

Comment: Whenever you're tempted to ask "is X possible?" consider: do you have cause to suspect this is *impossible*? What law of the universe would conspire to take this away from you? Bear in mind that just about any game-making environment out there is Turing complete, so if you can describe a mechanical process to produce your desired output, then you can express it in your language/engine of choice with enough elbow grease. Usually, these questions are really "how do I?" in disguise - you can get to your goal much faster by just trying it, and if you hit a snag, show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this using many way like:

**Solution # 1, Using sprite sheet like mechanism:** (not recommended)

It this way you will be having multiple texture for you character face and you will be changing character face texture over time.

Pros:

1. Easy to implement.

Cons:

1. Too many textures.
2. No run time controls.
3. Hard to make changes to the facial expression.

**Solution # 2, Using Blend shapes:**(recommended)

It this way you don't have to create too many texture instead you will be having only one texture.

Pros:

1. Only one texture to work with.
2. Full facial expression controls at run time.
3. Easy to edit.
4. Can create many expressions.

Cons:

1. time consuming at start.

[How to create Blend shapes.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvB6HajivSY)